# How to add Multiple ManyToOne mapping in single POJO and get records from multiple table?

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have tables
Order(orderno,orderdate,suppid)
Supplier(suppid,suppname)
orderdetails(orderdetailid,orderno)
how to get result like this using JPA orderno,orderdate,suppname,orderdetailid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name="suppid",nullable=false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Supplier supplierDetails;


    This will Join  one table to another and fetch the record for you.This code should be inside Order table POJO. and getter setter of supplier details as well.
```